# Lua reading dbus info

Tags: lua, dbus

The last few days I've looked on the internet and couldn't anything that worked.

What module can I use to read dbus with lua?

Answer (score 1):

I made some a long time ago; https://github.com/daurnimator/ldbus

also see https://github.com/luaforge/lua-dbus

Comment: Neither one worked.  I'm using popen with dbus-send to query the dbus.

Comment: File bugs with the respective projects then?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `lgi`:

https://github.com/pavouk/lgi/

It's actively developed, but it requires GObject libraries.